# Unknown column 'tokens.update_on' when importing mysql dump to new Redmine instance

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I'm in the process of upgrading an installation of Redmine from 3.0.3 to 3.3.3.

The process I always follow for this is to install a fresh Redmine on a new machine, import and sqldump from the current one, then copy the important stuff (files/config.yml/database.yml, plugins) over and run all the necessary steps. This has generally worked well in the past.

At the moment, after importing the sqldump, Redmine isn't starting and I'm getting an error I'm not able to figure out.

The mysql import appears to work:

```
mysql -u 'user' -p'mypassword' redmine < /home/redmine20170608.sql
```

Then I do the usual steps which all run with no errors:

```
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake tmp:sessions:clear
bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear
sudo service httpd restart
```

When I navigate to myredmine.com I get the "Internal Error" message. Check the logs and the out put is:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'tokens.updated_on' in 'field list': UPDATE `tokens` SET `tokens`.`updated_on` = '2017-06-09 07:10:56.515511' WHERE `tokens`.`user_id` = 1 AND `tokens`.`value` = '5a229e24fe73e8a43768c46af2275a8b4a60c9b3' AND `tokens`.`action` = 'session'):
  app/models/user.rb:425:in `verify_session_token'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:77:in `session_expired?'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:67:in `session_expiration'


Migrating to CreateRolesManagedRoles (20150528092912)
Started GET "/" for 72.155.92.149 at 2017-06-09 07:16:14 +0000
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'tokens.updated_on' in 'field list': UPDATE `tokens` SET `tokens`.`updated_on` = '2017-06-09 07:16:14.896744' WHERE `tokens`.`user_id` = 1 AND `tokens`.`value` = '5a229e24fe73e8a43768c46af2275a8b4a60c9b3' AND `tokens`.`action` = 'session'):
  app/models/user.rb:425:in `verify_session_token'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:77:in `session_expired?'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:67:in `session_expiration'
```

This is the code from line 425 of that file:

```
scope.update_all(:updated_on => Time.now) == 1
```

Which is inside this section:

```
  # Returns true if token is a valid session token for the user whose id is user_id
  def self.verify_session_token(user_id, token)
    return false if user_id.blank? || token.blank?

    scope = Token.where(:user_id => user_id, :value => token.to_s, :action => 'session')
    if Setting.session_lifetime?
      scope = scope.where("created_on > ?", Setting.session_lifetime.to_i.minutes.ago)
    end
    if Setting.session_timeout?
      scope = scope.where("updated_on > ?", Setting.session_timeout.to_i.minutes.ago)
    end
    scope.update_all(:updated_on => Time.now) == 1
  end
```

I usually find the error output for these to be relatively self explanatory but I don't know how to interpret this one.

I've deleted all of the plugins to make sure its not a compatibility issue and still getting the same problem.

The current Redmine is 3.0.3, running on Ruby 1.9.3-p551, Rails 4.2.1 and AWS Linux AMI 2010.03 (which I am advised to move away from).

The new Redmine is 3.3.3, running on Ruby 2.2.5-p319, Rails 4.2.7.1 and CentOS 7.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the code on line 425? share the method in application controller

Comment: what is scope ?

Comment: Updated again to include scope.

Comment: are you sure `Token` has a column `updated_on`? that's what the error is. What do you get for this `Token.column_names` in your console?

Comment: I' m not really sure - what should I do with 'Token.column_names'?

Comment: run that in your rails console, I assume that `Token` is a table

Comment: OK - no, it doesn't have a column called that. The Token table has columns id, user_id, action, value, and created_on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments the error is

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'tokens.updated_on'

There's no column called `updated_on` in `Token` model and you are trying to update it on *line 425*

```
scope.update_all(:updated_on => Time.now) == 1
```

You need to add migration for that column.

run following command in your terminal from app's root folder,

```
rails g migration AddUpdatedOnToToken updated_on:datetime

rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks - do you know how I can do this? I'm not very experienced with databases in general and mysql specifically.

Comment: When I run that first command I'm getting the error ```/home/centos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error)``` and yet when I tried it with sudo I get `command not found`.

Comment: well...that's a different error altogether..you don't seem to have access to db, or maybe password is wrong

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to manually add the required column. The way described in the first answer didn't work - as noted I kept getting permission denied. This is weird because there are only two mysql users and both have access to that database.

So the way to fix this was to log into mysql as the Redmine user and run these commands:

```
USE mydatabase;
ALTER TABLE tokens ADD updated_on VARCHAR(60);
```

And the issue was resolved - I was able to continue and access Redmine with no issues.